# Splide-Slider doesn't work on mobile-size browsers. Slide-Arrows move on but slides keep the same

Tags: javascript, css, slider, splidejs

I am currently developing a website for a friend, which uses the splide-slider. The Slider works perfectly fine on desktop-Browsers but if I edit the width of the browser, the slides aren't working any longer. I can click on the arrows to change the "active" dot, but the slide doesn't change. Does someone know why this could be?

Here's the website I am working on: https://www.flairdesignbyjessica.de/

The slider begings where the autoplay is already working.
This is the JS-Code I used to initialize the slider:

`var splide = new Splide( '.splide', { perPage: 3, focus  : 0, updateOnMove: true, type: 'loop', autoScroll: { speed: 1 }, } ).mount( window.splide.Extensions );`

I tried changing the value of "perpage" to 1, or using the breakpoints-option of splide, but that didn't change anything. Could it be the width or some of the elements?

Comment: It works on this codepen: https://codepen.io/syrizaldev/pen/WNgBgRB

But copying the codepens' JS and inserting it instead of using mine, didn't change it, so I assume it has to do with the css (or html?!)